# What's the C++ cin.eof()'s value represent?

Tags: c++

In istream, I use cin.getline() to accept some of the characters and I input the EOF signal(as my OS is MAC, I press control + D) then comes the second cin.getline() to accept the rest of the stream. 
However, I test the value of cin.eof(),3 times, before the first cin.getline(), between the first and second cin.getline() ,and  in the end.
And in this program, I all use the EOF signal to terminate this three cin.getline();

the code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout<<"now EOF:"<<cin.eof()<<endl;
    char character[10];
    cout<<"input ten digit character,with '!' in the middle,end with EOF(ctrl+d):"<<endl;
    cin.getline(character, 10,'!');
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"get the character:"<<endl;
    cout<<character<<endl;
    char character2[10];
    cout<<"now EOF:"<<cin.eof()<<endl;
    cout<<"press(ctrl+d):"<<endl;
    cin.getline(character2, 10,'!');
    //cin>>character2;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<character2<<endl;
    cout<<"now EOF:"<<cin.eof()<<endl;


}
```

the result is here:

```
now EOF:0
input ten digit character,with '!' in the middle,end with EOF(ctrl+d):
123!456

get the character:
123
now EOF:0
press(ctrl+d):

456

now EOF:1
```

but when I substitute cin.getline(character2, 10,'!') with the commented part cin>>character2 :

the result is:

```
now EOF:0
input ten digit character,with '!' in the middle,end with EOF(ctrl+d):
123!456

get the character:
123
now EOF:0
press(ctrl+d):

456
now EOF:0
```

I want to know,why this happen and how the cin.eof() value change.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `istream::eof()` returns `true` it means that **the previous input operation failed** because the stream was at the end of the file. That's why you can't use it to control an input loop: by the time it's true, the input has already failed. And that's why the input operations themselves can tell you whether they succeeded: that way you can loop as long as the input succeeds. This code

```
while (cin.getline(whatever)) {
    do_something(whatever);
}
```

will execute the loop each time the `getline` call reads a line. When `cin` reaches the end of the input, the `getline` call will fail, and the loop won't be executed. This code:

```
while (!cin.eof()) {
    cin.getline(whatever);
    do_something(whatever);
}
```

will call `do_something` even if the call to `getline` fails. **After** that call fails, on the next time through the loop, `cin.eof()` will return true and the loop will exit.

Answer (score 1):

In your second example, the new line character is still available to read - you've read a string, not a line.

See the missing extra newline in the output? That's the clue.

But more importantly, don't use `eof`. See [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: Did you mean that in the second example the "cin>> "regard the EOF signal as a string,and do not do anything ?